# Jquery slide effect only works in my computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, webserver, slide

The slide effect only works if I test the file in my computer, if I put in a linux/cpanel host it does not work. Please note, all .js files are external (in jquery server) I dont know what is wrong. Can somebody help me? I use chrome.

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="slide">
  teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeste
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in a console and check for errors?

Comment: Hit `F12` and press the **Console** button on the left-hand-side of the developer tools dialog's navigation menu. Copy/paste any errors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this fiddle doesn't work (using your sources for jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/YJaME/8/

But replacing it with Google's version of jQuery makes it work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YJaME/9/

It's the same code, with the only difference being what I am including in the `src`. Is there a reason why you are using the version that you are vs. Google's hosted one? If not I would see if changing this around helps any.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
  });
</script>

<div id="slide">
  teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeste
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with his code, and switching out the library source worked. It's weird perhaps, but it is an answer that gets it _working_.

Comment: @TrevorSenior i am having the same problem and did wht you said but didn't got the success